# Fetching the JSON on Table using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, html-table

I am using server PHP to retrieve the data from the database and store it in JSON format. Then JavaScript will create a table and the time is from `07:00 AM` to `07:00 PM` with 30-minute intervals. After that, the JavaScript must fetch that JSON data to that table according to column (`dayOfWeek`) and the Time (e.g. `07:00 AM - 07:30 AM`, and so on).

Since there are schedule that has a long duration (`07:00 AM - 10:00 AM` `MONDAY`), the row where the data are fetched must be combined using `rowspan` attribute to prevent duplication of the same data within the `Start time` and `End Time`.

My problem is it does not fetch the data to the HTML table. I've tried to fetch the data in the Console Tab (of the browser) and the JSON shows, but it is not shown on the table.

Here is the JavaScript:

```
function calculateRowspan(cellData, day, dayData) {
  let rowspan = 1;
  const timeText = cellData["time"];

  // Iterate through subsequent rows to check for matching details
  const currentIndex = dayData.indexOf(cellData);
  for (let i = currentIndex + 1; i < dayData.length; i++) {
    if (dayData[i]["time"] === timeText && dayData[i]["status"] === cellData["status"]) {
      rowspan++;
    } else {
      break;
    }
  }

  return rowspan;
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  function generateTimeSlots() {
    const startTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 7, 0, 0); // Set start time to 7:00 AM
    const endTime = new Date(0, 0, 0, 19, 0, 0); // Set end time to 7:00 PM
    const interval = 30 * 60 * 1000; // 30 minutes in milliseconds

    const tableBody = document.querySelector("tbody");
    const daysOfWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"];

    // Clear existing table content
    tableBody.innerHTML = '';

    for (let currentTime = startTime; currentTime < endTime; currentTime.setTime(currentTime.getTime() + interval)) {
      const row = document.createElement("tr");
      const timeText = currentTime.toLocaleTimeString([], {
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit'
        }) +
        " - " +
        new Date(currentTime.getTime() + interval).toLocaleTimeString([], {
          hour: '2-digit',
          minute: '2-digit'
        });

      row.innerHTML = '<td>' + timeText + '</td>' + new Array(7).fill('<td></td>').join('');
      tableBody.appendChild(row);
    }

    // Fetch class schedule data from the PHP script using AJAX
    $.ajax({
      url: "get-class-schedule.php",
      type: "GET",
      dataType: "json",
      success: function(data) {
        console.log("Data fetched successfully:", data);

        // Iterate through the received data and populate the table cells
        data.forEach(function(dayData, index) {
          const day = daysOfWeek[index];

          // Check if the array for the current day is empty
          if (dayData[day].length > 0) {
            dayData[day].forEach(function(cellData) {
              const timeText = cellData["time"];
              const matchingRow = Array.from(tableBody.rows).find(row => row.cells[0].textContent === timeText);

              if (matchingRow) {
                const cell = matchingRow.cells[index + 1]; // Skip the first cell (Time)
                const rowspan = calculateRowspan(cellData, day, dayData[day]);

                if (rowspan > 1) {
                  cell.setAttribute("rowspan", rowspan);
                  rowspanMap[day] = rowspan - 1; // Set rowspan for subsequent rows
                }

                cell.innerHTML = cellData["status"].replace(/<br>/g, "\n"); // Replace <br> with line breaks
              }
            });
          }
        });
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
      },
      complete: function() {
        console.log("AJAX request completed.");
      },
    });
  }

  // Call the function to generate time slots immediately
  generateTimeSlots();
});
```

And here is the HTML table:

```
<div class="card-body">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-white">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Time</th>
          <th>Monday</th>
          <th>Tuesday</th>
          <th>Wednesday</th>
          <th>Thursday</th>
          <th>Friday</th>
          <th>Saturday</th>
          <th>Sunday</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody class="small">
        <!-- JavaScript will populate time slots here -->
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lastly, the sample JSON data:

```
[
  {
    "Monday": [
      {
        "time": "07:00 AM - 08:00 AM",
        "status": "In"
      },
      {
        "time": "08:00 AM - 10:00 AM",
        "status": "In Class<br>Subject 101<br>BA 1-2<br>Room 3"
      },
      {
        "time": "10:00 AM - 12:00 PM",
        "status": "In Class<br>Subject 11<br>BA 1-2<br>Room 1"
      },
      {
        "time": "12:00 PM - 02:00 PM",
        "status": "In"
      },
      {
        "time": "02:00 PM - 04:00 PM",
        "status": "Consultation"
      },
      {
        "time": "04:00 PM - 07:00 PM",
        "status": "In Class<br>Subject 1<br>BA 1-2<br>Room 2"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Looking forward to your suggestions.

Comment: Few issues in your given code i,e : 1 . The `timeText` values doesn't have AM/PM attach to it . 2. When you comparing the first tds value with `timeText` this is will never match as your time return from backend in that there is diff of time is `> 30` mins ie: `08:00 AM - 10:00 AM` so `matchingRow` value will never be true .